# Excel VBA Function gives strange returns

Tags: vba, excel

My situation is as follow:

I have function one:

```
Function test(TestValue As String, TargetRange As Range) As String
     Dim rng2 As String   Dim C As Range


  For Each C In TargetRange
    If C.Text = TestValue Then
        If rng2 <> vbNullString Then
            rng2 = rng2 & "," & C.Address
        Else
            rng2 = C.Address
        End If
    End If
    Next   test = rng2 
End Function
```

This one looks in a range for cells with a specific value and add the cell adresses to a string. This works very well.

Second I have function number 2:

```
Function CountCellsByColor2(rData As String, cellRefColor As Range) As Long
    Dim indRefColor As Long
    Dim cellCurrent As Range
    Dim cntRes As Long
    Dim test As Long

    'Application.Volatile
    cntRes = 0
    indRefColor = cellRefColor.Cells(1, 1).Interior.Color
    For Each cellCurrent In Range(rData)
        If indRefColor = cellCurrent.Interior.Color Then
            cntRes = cntRes + 1
        End If
    Next cellCurrent

    CountCellsByColor2 = cntRes
End Function
```

This one uses the string with the addresses and check the cells for a given color and returns a number how many cells have the given color.

So far very simple.

Now my problem, when my strings has not more than 20 cell addresses everything works perfect but when I add to much around 31 the Color function Returns #Value!.

When I use it from out an other sheet lets say `=CountCellsByColor2(test("Apple";!SomeSheetF2:F300);H5)` for example. I get for some input nothing or the correct answer or #Value!.

So I don't really if I bounce to some limitation of excel or Vba. Or maybe my string of cells get to big. I hope somebody sees quickly what is going wrong.

Comment: Please see the edit to my answer.  It seems the limit you are running into is a 255 character limit to the Range statement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you are running into a limitation with the Union operator (the comma).  The Union method itself has a limit of 30 arguments, so, with your string creation method, returning an error at 31 would make some sense.

**EDIT:** It seems it is not the Union limitation that is applying. Rather the problem is the length of the argument for the Range object. When I tested, I did not see errors until I had about 40 cells in the argument.  Further empirical testing reveals that an error is created when the argument to the Range object is greater than 255 characters. This limitation may also apply to arguments to other VBA objects or statements or methods.

For minimal change to your existing code, try the following, which splits your comma separated list of ranges and tests them one at a time.

This is provided to help you understand what your coding problem is.  There 
may be more efficient methods of coding what you want to do, however.

---

```
Function CountCellsByColor2(rData As String, cellRefColor As Range) As Long
    Dim indRefColor As Long
    Dim cellCurrent As Variant
    Dim cntRes As Long
    Dim test As Long

    'Application.Volatile
    cntRes = 0
    indRefColor = cellRefColor.Cells(1, 1).Interior.Color

    For Each cellCurrent In Split(rData, ",")
        If indRefColor = Range(cellCurrent).Interior.Color Then
            cntRes = cntRes + 1
        End If
    Next cellCurrent

    CountCellsByColor2 = cntRes
End Function
```

---

Comment: The use of Split solved my problem. Only I still have another problem. When I use the two function from another sheet and reference the Range from an other sheet for example 

=CountCellsByColor2(test("Apple";!SomeSheetF2:F300);H5

The Result is Blank. Could it be that the function get to big or does it have to calculate to much. On the sheet with the specific Range it works flawless.

Comment: That is because your `test` function is only returning the cell address.  For a Range Object where you don't specify the worksheet, the active sheet is always assumed.  If you want to return a string that includes the worksheet name, set the `External` argument of the `Address` property, in your `test` UDF, to `True`

Comment: @ Ron I set the External argument of the Address property but it didn't solved the problem. It is not a sheet outside my current workbook but just another sheet in the same workbook. I noticed that some input with fewer cells in eh string gives the right result.But input with to much cells in the string give nothing back. Looks like something to do with a delay or complexity or something like that. Do you know something like that, things that can trigger this effect.

Comment: @BasdeKoning It shouldn't matter if it is in the same or a different workbook. Excel will look at the sheet name, which is what you need.  Use some breakpoints to figure out what is going on.  Or post a copy of your workbook, with sensitive information removed, at some public sharing site, and post a link here, if you can't figure it out.

Comment: I started with a clean Excel and build up my Worksheet and evrything works fine now. Maybe I had to much formules running arround. The first excel was build in excel 2010 and the new one in 2016. Maybe the version makes the differents.

Answer (score 0):

Make the first arg is a *String*:

[image]

Comment: My function test returns a String. What is the input for the CountCellsColor2 function. So that shouldn't  be the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Why do you use a String to collect the cells? A collection makes it so much easier.

```
Function Test(TestValue As String, TargetRange As Range) As Collection
    Dim c As Range

    'Initialize collection
    Set Test = New Collection

    'Loop through range
    For Each c In TargetRange
        If (c.Text = TestValue) Then
            Test.Add c
        End If
    Next c
End Function

Function CountCellsByColor2(rData As Collection, cellRefColor As Range) As Long
    Dim indRefColor As Long
    Dim cellCurrent As Range

    'Determine color
    indRefColor = cellRefColor.Cells(1, 1).Interior.Color

    'Loop through all cells
    For Each cellCurrent In rData
        If (cellCurrent.Interior.Color = indRefColor) Then
            CountCellsByColor2 = CountCellsByColor2 + 1
        End If
    Next cellCurrent
End Function
```